# 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of “/”

Tags: networking, ftp, windows-server-2012-r2, filezilla

I'm trying to solve this error searching the web, without any success.

The error is:

> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"

My software:

- Windows server 2013 and last filezilla server

My topology:

- Server wired to router - Router with a dynamic IP from ISP, dynamic dns updated.

My settings:

- PASV mode with ports 51000-61000
- Retrieve external ip with http://ip.filezilla-project.org/ip.php
- Enabled FTP over TLS with port 990

Where I opened my ports

- router: local and public 21, local 51000 public 51000-61000, local and public 990 (ALL tcp)
- Windows Firewall: both directions, ports 21, 51000-61000, 990.

On my lan it works perfectly. I think there's something wrong with router port forwarding configuration. Here it is.

[My port forwarding configuration on router](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hg4co.png)

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

I add a log of my ftp server:

```
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> PBSZ 0
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> 200 PBSZ=0
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> PROT P
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> 200 Protection level set to P
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> PWD
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> 257 "/" is current directory.
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> TYPE I
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> 200 Type set to I
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> PASV
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> 227 Entering Passive Mode (my,ip,addr,ess,205,93)
(000013)06/11/2017 21:50:57 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> MLSD
(000013)06/11/2017 21:51:07 - user (my.ip.add.ress)> 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
```

I add the ftp server configuration screens too just in case.

[General Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LAoz0.png)

[PASV Mode settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOKGr.png)

[FTP over TLS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHxoO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The router mapping seems suspicious, as you have correctly guessed. It looks like you have all public ports in range 51000–61000 mapped to a single internal port 51000. What would explain, why the client is not able to connect to port 52573.

If your router is not able to map a range of internal ports, you can configure your FTP server to use only a narrow range (like 51000–51010) and configure those ports one-by-one.

See also [How many data channel ports do I need for an FTPS server running behind NAT?](https://serverfault.com/q/709984/168875)